# UnexpectedValueException laravel :protocol error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-exceptions

I am doing a project in Laravel 5.6 homestead. I got this error after i ran php artisan cache:config, the command ran successfully but after I ran this command and refreshed the url in my browser, I get the following error
Now no routes are opening even the main url ecommerce.test showing this error. Im a Laravel beginer.

Any idea how to solve this???

**There is no existing directory at "C:\Laravel_Homestead_Projects\ecommerce\storage\logs" and its not buildable: Protocol error**

Comment: Does the `logs` directory exist in "\Laravel_Homestead_Projects\ecommerce\storage"? You may want to create it if it isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
go to `storage\framework\cache` and delete anything there is there.

2)

```
homestead ssh
```

3)
in your project folder:  `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Yes i did the same and also ran composer cache:clear then composer config:cache and problem is solved now -- answer accepted